# Problem with consuming a laravel 5.8 API in Angular8

Tags: angular, api, response, angular8

I've developd my own API in laravel 5.8 and consuming it in Angular8.

my API Working fine when i'm using it with Postman, but problem comes when i use it in angular8. i'm getting null response from laravel api, if i hit that url from browser then i'm getting json data but unable to get in angular8. and there is no error in console.

this is my service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  public url = 'http://archimate360.localhost/api/products';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getProducts(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  getProductDetails(id){
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'products?id=' + id);
  }
  createProduct(data){
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'products',data);
  }
  updateProduct(data){
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'products' , data);
  }
  deleteProduct(id){
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'products?id='  + id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to subscribe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a Cors middleware: App\Http\Middleware\Cors.php? if not try this 
 [1](https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1)

If you have added CORS middleware then try this code in the **.ts** file. If you are receiving any data it will display it on console, and if you are facing any error it will also display it on the console which will help us recognize the error

```
constructor(
private dataService: DataService
){ }


ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getProducts().subscribe(
      data => {
       console.log(data)
      },
      error => {
      console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is

```
getProducts(): any {
    return this.http
        .get(this.API_URL + '/product')
        .map((res: Response) => {
            return res;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```